# iPhone Core Data "executeFetchRequest" memory leak with "NSAutoreleasePool"

Tags: iphone, core-data

There is a method to do `executeFetchRequest`, which is tested severals times without an error, but when I check that with Instruments, there is a leak of `NSAutoReleasePool` every time that method is called. Anyone have idea about that?

Comment: did you get the exception message? if you don't see it printed after continuing, you can do this: `po $rax` in the simulator

Comment: What's your threading like? What is the NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType for your NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: Post some code please.